# Test explorer visual studio 2015 not discovering specflow tests

Tags: visual-studio-2015, specflow

Not sure if it's a visual studio bug or if I am missing the obvious, but it's a bit of hit and miss.

Sometimes Visual Studio discovers the tests, most of the times I can only see the marquee progress bar and nothing else.

Any ideas about why ?

**EDITED**

What happens is this:

Sometimes tests do not show
Most of the time tests show but when building/rebuilding solution than marquee progress bar goes in a infinite loop and the run Selected test and Debug selected test are both DISABLED and therefore cannot run test.The output windows shows nothing.

Comment: Which unit test provider are you using?

Comment: I am using mstest as unitprovider

Comment: Did you installed Update3 for VisualStudio 2015?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look in the Output Pane/Test output if there are some messages, that indicate why the tests are not visible.
SpecFlow generates normal MSTest test cases with the attributes. So the test explorer should find them every time without any extra work to do.

Comment: I have edited my question giving more details.A pain. Can you run any other Free GUI. EG Nunit Gui runner does it work with 2015? Basically I don t want to use test explorer to run my tests but I need a free GUI

Comment: There is a NUnit2 GUI Runner but no one for NUnit3.
All test framework use today test adapters for the test explorer in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in `Specflow.Tools.MSBuild.Generation` Version=2.3.2.

A short summary of it goes like this: Specflow finds `.feature` files
and if any of the corresponding `.feature.cs` files are missing or
out of date, it will generate them and add them to a list of files
called `SpecFlowGeneratedFiles`. The `.csproj` contains a section which
compiles the `SpecFlowGeneratedFiles` into the assembly. If the files
are not included, then there are no tests in the assembly, therefore
no tests are discovered.

In the event that all the .feature.cs files are already present and
up-to-date, the `SpecFlowGeneratedFiles` are not set, and you get 
an infuriating situation where the tests have mysteriously disappeared.
You can verify this bug by deleting any one of the generated `.feature.cs`
files from the disk and build again.

A workaround is to edit your .csproj and add a section after `AfterUpdateFeatureFilesInProject`.

```
<Target Name="AfterUpdateFeatureFilesInProject">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="@(SpecFlowGeneratedFiles)" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<!-- Workaround Specflow 2.3 MSBuild bug. SpecFlowGeneratedFiles is not set if UpdateFeatureFilesInProject is up-to-date
   causing tests not to be discovered, as they are not included in the project -->
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="**/*.feature.cs" Exclude="@(SpecFlowGeneratedFiles)">
    <DependentUpon>%(Filename)</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```